# Copy selected row data when click on row in listview and value send to new activity for display as textview

Tags: android, listview, onclick, listitem, selectlistitem

Hiiii  I want when i should click the row data , it seems to copy the value of row and pass to another activity for display as textview. I am taking data by single row values from table using mysql. A "Hope of Help" will be appreciated from your side PLEASE !!

//MainActivity.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.ParseException;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
/*
 * @author Firzan Ghulam
 */
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    JSONArray jArray;
    String result = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    StringBuilder sb = null; 
    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
    String targetmonth;

    int responseCode;
    int listItemCount=0;
    ListView listview ;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        new LoadData().execute();

         // listening to single list item on click
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
              int position, long id) {

              // selected item
              String product = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();

              // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
              Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleListItem.class);
              // sending data to new activity
              i.putExtra("product", product);
              startActivity(i);

          }
        });


    } 



    private class LoadData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>   { 
        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;  
        @Override
        // can use UI thread here
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, ""," Can you just see your roof...");  
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {  
            try{

                     listview.setAdapter(new DataAdapter(MainActivity.this,al.toArray(new String[al.size()])));


                     this.progressDialog.dismiss();





                }
                catch(Exception e){ 
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }  
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
            // HTTP post 
                    try { 
                        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
                        try{
                        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://palaknehazz.com/app/ap.php");

                        StringEntity se = new StringEntity("envelope",HTTP.UTF_8);
                        httppost.setEntity(se); 
                        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
                        // Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established.
                        int timeoutConnection = 3000;
                        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
                        // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT) 
                        // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
                        int timeoutSocket = 3000;
                        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket); 

                        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        is = entity.getContent(); 
                        }
                        catch(Exception e){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        //buffered reader
                        try{
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                is, "iso-8859-1"), 80);
                        sb = new StringBuilder();
                        sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
                        String line = "0";
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            sb.append(line + "\n");
                        }
                        is.close();
                        result = sb.toString();

                        System.out.println("Magu data aagaya"+result);
                        }
                        catch(Exception e){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        try{
                        jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                        JSONObject json_data = null;
                        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                            json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i); 
                            //targetamount=json_data.getString("targetamount");
                            targetmonth=json_data.getString("targetmonth");
                            //targetyear = json_data.getString("targetyear"); 
                            al.add(targetmonth); 
                            //al1.add(targetyear);
                            //al2.add(targetamount);  

                            //listItemCount=al2.size();
                        }
                    }
                    catch(JSONException e){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }   
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                    //  Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection" + e.toString());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }  
                     catch (Exception e) {
                            //  Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection" + e.toString());
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }       


            return null; 
        }


    } 








}
```

//Data Adapter

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView; 
public class DataAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context mContext; 
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    String targetmonth;
    String[] month;

    public DataAdapter(Context c, String[] month) {
        this.month = month;

        mContext = c;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(c); 
    } 
    public int getCount() {
        return month.length;
    } 
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    } 
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    } 
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.customgrid, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.month = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.targetmonth); 

            if (position == 0) {
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        try {

            holder.month.setText(month[position]);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        return convertView;
    } 
    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView month;

    }

}
```

//SingleListItem

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SingleListItem extends Activity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.meter);

        TextView txtProduct = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.product_label);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        // getting attached intent data
        String product = i.getStringExtra("product");
        // displaying selected product name
        txtProduct.setText(product);

    }
}
```

//Logcat error

```
05-14 22:48:02.644: D/dalvikvm(461): GC_CONCURRENT freed 56K, 2% free 14428K/14663K, paused 8ms+6ms
05-14 22:48:03.051: D/gralloc_goldfish(461): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
05-14 22:48:05.121: I/System.out(461): Magu data aagaya[{"id":"1","targetmonth":"Karan is a intelligegnt guy if you know what i mean haha frieds plays very important role i TV serial life i believe hahaha i mean who guess for being myself"},{"id":"2","targetmonth":"He's the unpredictable foolish man you are looking forward for seriously"},{"id":"3","targetmonth":"Same here you are looking"}]
05-14 22:48:08.294: D/AndroidRuntime(461): Shutting down VM
05-14 22:48:08.294: W/dalvikvm(461): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
05-14 22:48:08.341: E/AndroidRuntime(461): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-14 22:48:08.341: E/AndroidRuntime(461): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
05-14 22:48:08.341: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at com.demo.php.listview.MainActivity$LoadData$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:94)
05-14 22:48:08.341: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:292)
05-14 22:48:08.341: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1058)
05-14 22:48:08.341: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2514)
05-14 22:48:08.341: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3168)
05-14 22:48:08.341: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
05-14 22:48:08.341: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-14 22:48:08.341: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-14 22:48:08.341: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
05-14 22:48:08.341: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-14 22:48:08.341: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-14 22:48:08.341: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-14 22:48:08.341: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-14 22:48:08.341: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your main Activity change

```
// selected item
              String product = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
```

by

```
// selected item
              String product = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.targetmonth)).getText().toString();
```